# Output powershell caml query to table

Tags: powershell, caml-query

This has to be real easy but I just cant find an answer on google that will work in my case. I am running a ps1 file that caml queries a document library. I just want to organize these results into a table. Thats it.

Closest I got is `$queryResults | select Title` but this only make s a Title column and only works once for some reason. I have multiple queries and will have multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Format-Table` or its alias `ft` will do this for you.

```
$queryResults | Format-Table -auto
```

[Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx)

Comment: I need to choose a select number of columns. So `$queryResults | Format-Table -Property Col1, Col2, Col3` is successfully organizing my data into columns, but no data is filling them.

Comment: http://www.windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-with-a-purpose-blog-36/scripting-languages/fun-tricks-with-format-table-and-select-137400 check this out